# Couldn't get rid of react warning of unique key in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my below code? I had key={obj._id} and I expect I will not see the warning but I'm still getting it.

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop. Check the render method..

```
renderListItems(items){
        return(
            <div>
            {map(items, obj =>
                <div key={obj._id} className="panel-body panel-row">
                    <div  className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <h2 className="title">{obj.display_name}</h2>
                            <p className="edited">Last edited on {moment(obj.updated_at).format('DD MMM YYYY')}</p>
                            <div className="actions_wrap">
                                <Link to={`/mall-promospace/edit/${obj._id}`}>Edit</Link>
                                <a onClick={()=> this.setState({openConfirmationModal:true, selectedItemId: obj._id, selectedItemName: obj.display_name})}>Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: The first question, of course, is "are you sure your _id fields are unique?"

Comment: This code on its own looks fine, so either the error is being generated from a different iterator, or two or more of your ids are duplicated.

Comment: @speckledcarp yes. And Jivings I don't have duplicated ids.

Comment: What does the render method look like?  Maybe nothing wrong there... but the error does point you to a different method than the one you have in the question...

Comment: Error message seems incomplete...it should be..`.....Check the render method of <Component_Name>..`.

Comment: If you have multiple methods being called from `render()` method and you are unsure about which method is causing the error, you can comment out the specific method and see if error is gone. This way you can pin point the error.

Comment: Can you show the contents of that `map` function? In case it's masking some strange goings on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are coding some things wrong. You should apply the function "map" over an array.

Try this:

```
renderListItems(items){
        return(
            <div>
            {items.map(obj =>
                <div key={obj._id} className="panel-body panel-row">
                    <div  className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <h2 className="title">{obj.display_name}</h2>
                            <p className="edited">Last edited on {moment(obj.updated_at).format('DD MMM YYYY')}</p>
                            <div className="actions_wrap">
                                <Link to={`/mall-promospace/edit/${obj._id}`}>Edit</Link>
                                <a onClick={()=> this.setState({openConfirmationModal:true, selectedItemId: obj._id, selectedItemName: obj.display_name})}>Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items.map((obj, i) => <div key={i}></div>)
```